# Using .getElementsByClassName to access multiple popups

Tags: javascript, arrays, popup

I am attempting to use the following javascript to create various popups.Image popups when text is clicked. The problem is that when I click any of the text containers, all of the popup images appear.  I know I am missing something obvious. Any help would be much appreciated. Here is the JS code:

```
function myFunction() {

var popup = document.getElementsByClassName("myPopup");

for(var i=0; i<popup.length; i++) {

popup[i].classList.toggle('show');
}
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()"><span class="castName">Viola,</span>
<span class="popuptext myPopup"><img src=Viola_1.jpg        
style="width:300px;height:100%;" alt="Viola"><p>Miss Ellen Terry as Viola, mid   
to late 19th century</p></span></div>
```

Comment: How does the `text` relate to the correct `popup`?

Comment: Hi, the text is a container that, when clicked, activates a popup image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function gets a list of elements and toggle the class 'show' to every element instead of the element you want. You have to pass in the element to the function.

You can change the onclick event for each div from:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction()">
```

to:

```
<div class="popup" onclick="myFunction(this)">
```

Then in your javascript

```
function myFunction(element){
    if (element){ //If the element is passed into this function
        element.getElementsByClassName("myPopup")[0].toggle('show');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thum, this was very helpful.  I ended up changing the HTML as you suggested and did the following to the javascript, which worked perfectly:

```
function myFunction(element) {
var popup = element.getElementsByClassName('myPopup');
var i;
for( i=0; i<popup.length; i--) {
popup[i].classList.toggle('show');
}
}
```